# Why is loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore not recognized?

Tags: android, google-play-games

I am currently getting the current player score in Google Play Games Services by using:

```
loadPlayerCenteredScores(this, LEADER, LeaderboardVariant.TIME_SPAN_WEEKLY, LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_PUBLIC, 1, true);
```

Which sound stupid as I can see in the Documentation:[loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesClient.html#loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore%28com.google.android.gms.games.leaderboard.OnPlayerLeaderboardScoreLoadedListener,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29)

> Asynchronously load the currently signed in player's score for a given
>   leaderboard.

But as you can see on below screenshot, this sounds impossible, while the other methods are working.

[image]

The [listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/OnPlayerLeaderboardScoreLoadedListener.html) is also not available:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you've got the parameters wrong. There's only 5 parameters, not 7. Here's what I've got:

```
...
activity.gameHelper.getGamesClient().loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore(
    this, getResources().getString(R.string.leaderboard_level1),
    LeaderboardVariant.TIME_SPAN_ALL_TIME, LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_PUBLIC);
...

@Override
public void onPlayerLeaderboardScoreLoaded(int statusCode, LeaderboardScore score) {}
```